# Custom ip outside of amazon's block with elestic ip

Tags: networking, ip, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a ec2 instance running that needs access to a serves that has blacklisted amazon's entire ip block. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) I can use elestic ip to assign a custom ip address but I still need an ip outside of amazon's ip block. I have googled everything I can think of but can't find how to obtain such an ip. How would I go about this?

Comment: More information would be helpful.  What's the nature of the service and what ports does it use to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

connect to a VPN first, and then you will get an IP address from that VPN.